# Algorithm design: can you provide a solution to the knapsack problem where there is no maximum weight constraint?

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

I am not able to find suitable algorithm for my problem. my problem is as follows:
There are n number of tasks. Each task is replicated different number of times. Two replicas of same task should not be on same agent. assign the replicas to agent such that the sum of replicas on each agent is approximately same. There is no weight constraint on the agent.
can this be solved by knapsack?

Comment: The knapsack problem assumes different values and weights for the items. Do the tasks (replicas) have different weights?

Comment: replicas of same task have same weight

Answer (score 0):

A knapsack problem without weights is just about sorting descending for value and taking as much as you like. So it does not make that much sense without the weight constraint - because now no optimization needed.

I also see no connection to your agents here.

The problem is quite simple to solve:

1. Sort the agents ascending by the length of their queues
2. and give the next job to the first one that not already has a copy of that task.
3. repeat until all tasks are assigned

Comment: I want the replicas to be arranged on the agent in order to minimize the maximum load on the agents. i want all the agents to have approx same load.

Comment: I found makespan minimization algorithm is similar to what i need. But I am struggling to write it according to my requirements.